# LINQ: ignore ORDER BY for the records have the same name

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two tables "merged" into one list through

```
table1.AddRange(table2);
```

| employee_id | first_name | last_name | email | department | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | john@example.com | IT | 150 |
| 2 | John | Johnson | emily@example.com | HR | 250 |
| 3 | Michael | Davis | michael@example.com | Sales | 200 |

I have ordered this table using `OrderByDescending(x => x.quantity)`
which results in

| employee_id | first_name | last_name | email | department | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John | Johnson | emily@example.com | HR | 250 |
| 3 | Michael | Davis | michael@example.com | Sales | 200 |
| 1 | John | Smith | john@example.com | IT | 150 |

Now what I want to do is ignore `quantity` for the records which has the same name and put these records under another.

This is the result I want:

| employee_id | first_name | last_name | email | department | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John | Johnson | emily@example.com | HR | 250 |
| 1 | John | Smith | john@example.com | IT | 150 |
| 3 | Michael | Davis | michael@example.com | Sales | 200 |

Is this possible to do using LINQ?

Comment: You can just daisy chain OrderBy with ThenBy(). So in your case table1.OrderBy(s => s.first_name).ThenByDescending(s => s.quantity) would give you a list that is sorted by first_name and then descending quantity

Comment: @ChrisFromTheBlock This makes sense but doesn't work as I wanted when I tried, there might be another issue with my code,thank you

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to `GroupBy` employee, then sort with `OrderBy` and then use `SelectMany` to get a single list:

```cpp
var results = table.GroupBy(x => x.employee_id)
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.quantity))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```